# Two threads in use but also shows warnings about migrations when is none

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, ef-core-3.1

Something has been worrying me about my design of how I access the dbconext for I have been getting a couple of clashes saying that the dbcontext is in use by another thread. Also the message claims there is migrations to be run but their is def not the migrations are up to date. I am using asp.net 3.1 and Entity framework core 3.1.5

In My startup.cs I use the following to setup the context

```
services.AddDbContext<MISDBContext>
(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")), ServiceLifetime.Transient);
```

In my controller I inject it in the following way

```
private readonly MISDBContext _context;


public MISObjectsController(MISDBContext context, IStringLocalizer<MISObjectsController> localizer,
               IStringLocalizer<SharedResource> sharedLocalizer, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, IToastNotification toast) {
        _context = context;
        _sharedLocalizer = sharedLocalizer;
        _userManager = userManager;
        var list = _userManager.Users.Select(x => new SelectListItem() { Text = x.FirstName.ToUpperInvariant() + " " + x.LastName.ToUpperInvariant(), Value = x.Id.ToString() }).ToListAsync();
        ViewBag.Users = list;
        _toast = toast;   
}
```

Then in some function I would use it as such but I also do this inside of view components and am wondering is that how things are clashing saying that there is two threads in process.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddToAuditTrail(string updateInfo) {
        var userId = GetCurrentTennantId().Result;
        var caseOfficer = _context.Users.Where(w => w.Id == userId.ToString()).FirstOrDefault();
        Int32.TryParse(TempData.Peek("CaseId").ToString(), out int resultCaseId);
        MISAuditTrail _auditrail = new MISAuditTrail();
        _auditrail.MISObjectId = resultCaseId;
        _auditrail.TennantId = userId;
        _auditrail.CreatedBy = caseOfficer.FirstName + caseOfficer.LastName.Substring(0, 1);
        _auditrail.Action = updateInfo;
        _auditrail.AuditType = (int)MISAuditTrail.AudItTypes.NOTES;
        _auditrail.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
        _auditrail.isActive = true;
        _auditrail.isDeleted = false;

        _context.Add(_auditrail);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        _toast.AddSuccessToastMessage("You have added an update to the case");

        return RedirectToAction("Edit", new { id = resultCaseId });
    }
```

If someone could inlighiten me as to why am getting the two threads in use error that would be great.

Comment: firstly I would change var caseOfficer =  await... FirstOrDefaultAsync, the line above, I would use GetAwaiter().GetResult() if you can't use await that is, if you still get errors please post them. Also a side note, separate layers for controller  and data.

Comment: It is not a good idea to do database queries in a constructor. You really should do it in the action method.

Comment: where are the two queies I am mearly showing you an example I only see one query the userList @juunas:

Comment: @Rav Just to note it is in my dal layer am just showing a cut down example for complentess

Comment: @rav is it legal to do GetResult() or can u just use .Result what is the difference?

Comment: @rogue39nin you'd want to use getawaiter as all errors will be bought back, you'll lose the stack with .result